# How to retrieve data from an ICollection<T> where T is unknown

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I know that my type is a `ICollection<T>`. I know that `T` is a primitive type, and I know that `T` can be turned into a string with `ToString()`. I have the `Type` object of `T` (By using: `Type genericType = info.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];`

I do not know how to get the items in that collection out and into another collection of a known type (Like a `List<string>`). Thankfully because all I want are the values of it's items as a string I can use `ToString()` on each one regardless of it's type (constrained to primitives).

I use this in another area of my program to get the values of all the properties of a class as long as they are primitive. I have tried casting the `Type` object as the generic argument for an `ICollection<T>` and that did not work.

Edit: I have an `object` that I know is an `ICollection<T>`, but I cannot seem use LINQ on it till it's casted to an `ICollection<T>`, I cannot cast to that because `T` is "unknown" (I have retrieved the `Type` of `T` but am not sure where to run with that).

Answer (score 3):

Since you start with generic collection and `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use LINQ:

```
List<string> res = coll.Select(elem => elem.ToString()).ToList();
```

Edit - you can cast the object to non-generic `IEnumerable` or `ICollection`, then call `Cast<object>` on that to get a generic collection (you can do that because you just want to call `ToString` on elements):

```
object obj = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

IEnumerable res = obj as IEnumerable;
List<string> result = res.Cast<object>().Select(e => e.ToString()).ToList();

foreach (var e in result)
    Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Comment: Hi w.b I have an `object` that I know is a `ICollection<T>`, I can't seem to use LINQ on a plain old object though. I obtained this object by retrieving the value of a property from another object through reflection and verified that it is an `ICollection<>` and that `T` is a primitive type.

Comment: You can also cast to `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable` in case the code should be more strict.